# FOL: What does the axiom schema A ⊃ (B ⊃ A) actually mean?

Tags: logic

Of course, A ⊃ (B ⊃ A) works out to be true via truth function/table for material conditionals.

Does this mean that when you're doing proofs, if you had P written down as a true statement, then you could write down Q ⊃ P as a consequence?

And would that mean then P ENTAILS Q ⊃ P since (I think) a proof means logical consequence?

On one hand, this seems to fit the definition of entailment/logical consequence that says the premises can't be true while conclusion is false. (similar to the truth table for the material conditional)

On the other hand, that'd also mean that any true statement A ENTAILS that any statement B ⊃ A, regardless of any "relevance" between A and B... So, would the argument, "1 + 1 = 2, THEREFORE if triangles have 3 sides, then 1 + 1 = 2" be valid?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: The only way $A\supset (B\supset A)$ is false is if $A$ is true while $B\supset A$ is false, which, in turn, is only false if $B$ is true while $A$ is false, a contradiction.

Comment: Are the statements in the paragraphs correct?

Comment: It means that in a proof you can always add an unnecessary premise. See Weakening.

Comment: So does a true statement A entail B ⊃ A?

Comment: Yup, thats what the axiom says

Comment: Regarding "relevance" between A and B, see [Relevance Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/).